# normalize date and calculate start and end in loop

Tags: javascript, date, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to transform a set of data which involves date. I have no control over the backend I have this set of data

```
[
{id:123,date:'2017-05-01',name:'Sam'},
{id:123,date:'2017-05-02',name:'Sam'},
{id:123,date:'2017-05-03',name:'Sam'},
{id:456,date:'2017-05-02',name:'Kate'},
{id:456,date:'2017-05-03',name:'Kate'},
{id:456,date:'2017-05-04',name:'Kate'},
{id:456,date:'2017-05-05',name:'Kate'},
{id:456,date:'2017-05-06',name:'Kate'}
...
...
]
```

How can I turn it into this?

```
[{name:'Same',start_date:'2017-05-01',end_date:'2017-05-03',total_days:3},
{name:'Kate',start_date:'2017-05-02',end_date:'2017-05-06',total_days:5}]
```

Comment: You'd probably iterate over the array of objects and work out the first and last for a particular id, then get the difference in days between the two. You don't need to worry about dates until the difference part. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can get unique names first, then `map` over these names with filtered arrays, sorted by date:

```js
const arr = [
{id:123,date:'2017-05-01',name:'Sam'},
{id:123,date:'2017-05-02',name:'Sam'},
{id:123,date:'2017-05-03',name:'Sam'},
{id:456,date:'2017-05-02',name:'Kate'},
{id:456,date:'2017-05-03',name:'Kate'},
{id:456,date:'2017-05-04',name:'Kate'},
{id:456,date:'2017-05-05',name:'Kate'},
{id:456,date:'2017-05-06',name:'Kate'}
];

const res = [...new Set(arr.map(({name}) => name))] // get unique names with Set and convert it into array
  .map(n => { // for each name
    // filter array by name and sort by date
    const el = arr.filter(e => e.name === n).sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date));
    return {
      name: n,
      total_days: el.length,
      start_date: (el.length) ? el.shift().date : null, // date in first array item
      end_date: (el.length) ? el.pop().date : null // date in last array item
    }
  })

console.log(res)
```